# Anonymous token even if logged in in public pages

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm having some trouble setting my security.

I want a page to be accessible both by anonymous and by logged in members. I want it to show different content depending on the situation (in fact, i want to still be logged in as a member when i go on it).

The page I want to give public access is ^/profile.

I set my security.yml like that :

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

   # Firewall pour les pages de connexion, inscription, et récupération de mot de passe
        login:
           pattern: ^/(login$|register|resetting) # Les adresses de ces pages sont login, register et resetting
            anonymous: true                        # On autorise bien évidemment les anonymes sur ces pages # Firewall principal pour le reste de notre site
        public:
           pattern:            ^/profile
           anonymous:          true
           homepage:
           pattern: ^/$
               anonymous: true
               main:
                  pattern: ^/                           # ^/ = tout ce qui commence par / = tout notre site
        form_login:                            # On définit notre méthode d'authentification
            provider: fos_userbundle           # On lie l'authentification au provider définit plus haut
            remember_me: true                  # On active la possibilité du "Se souvenir de moi" (désactivé par défaut) 
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%                      # On définit la clé pour le remember_me (%secret% est un parametre de parameters.yml)
        anonymous: false                       # On autorise les utilisateurs anonymes (non identifiés)
        logout: true                           # On autorise la déconnexion manuelle (désactivé par défaut)
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"          

   access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My problem is that when I'm logged in and I access this page, it's like i'm not logged in (i've got my log in button) because the firewall give me an anonymous token.

thanks for your help.
Scaff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common pitfalls in authentication:

> **Multiple firewalls don't share security context**
>   If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically. Different firewalls are like different security systems. To do this you have to explicitly specify the same Firewall Context for different firewalls. ***But usually for most applications, having one main firewall is enough.***

So put all under one main firewall and use ACLs as in the [FOSUSerBundle installation step 4](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml).

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                remember_me: true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%          

   access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i didn't understand what they meant by security context but it's crystal clear now !

Comment: Security context: A (authenticated) security token of the firewall IMHO. This the reason why you are not authenticated in a second firewall, if you logged in the first.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot with the answer. I was trying to configure two secured areas with no results.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are not quite correctly inserted the file, so I can not say for sure. But you probably have 2 firewall for one url. Its a main firewall

```
main: 
    pattern: ^/
```

and a public firewall

```
public:
    pattern: ^/profile
```

Try to specify only one firewall.

Quote from [official documenation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html):

*Multiple firewalls don't share security context
If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically. Different firewalls are like different security systems. To do this you have to explicitly specify the same Firewall Context for different firewalls. But usually for most applications, having one main firewall is enough.*

Comment: i tried to have that kind of pattern for public pages : `(^/(login$|register|resetting|profile/[0-9A-Za-z]?)|^/$)`

and for private pages : `^/[0-9A-Za-z]+` but the problem is still there, on public pages, i'm like not logged in ...
thanks for your help anyway

Comment: try to remove `homepage` and `public` firewall

Comment: thanks, but that's what i did, I just have two firewalls now ! (one for public pages, and one for private ones)